# ¿Existe un equivalente masculino de "musa"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

Vaya de primeras que mi respuesta a esta pregunta sería que no lo hay, pero bueno, a ver si me explico. Hoy día la segunda acepción de *[musa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q8CVxNy)* es:

> Inspiración del artista o escritor.

La inspiración de los artistas y escritores puede ser muy variada, pero a lo largo del tiempo se conocen casos en los que esta inspiración venía personificada por alguien, generalmente una mujer que inspira a un artista varón, dado que se hace la comparación de dicha mujer con [las musas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musa) de la antigüedad. Sin embargo, ¿qué pasa cuando la fuente de inspiración se personifica en un hombre?

Encuentro en la Wikipedia en inglés [el siguiente ejemplo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BillyBoy*):

> BillyBoy* (born 10 March 1960) is an artist, socialite and fashion designer who was a muse of Andy Warhol.

Dado que BillyBoy* es un hombre, ¿cómo se diría en español? Yo entiendo que se diría "la musa" igualmente, aunque me gustaría saber si hay otras opciones. ¿Cómo se está reflejando este caso en la literatura española? ¿Se usa "musa"? ¿Se usa "el muso" al estilo de "miembros y miembras"? ¿Se evitaría el término en favor de decir "era la inspiración de Andy Warhol"? ¿Hay algún otro término o concepto equivalente a "musa" que usar con los hombres?

Comment: **Por definición** no. Las musas eran deidades femeninas. No masculinas. ...diseñador quien fue **una musa/inspiración** para AW... o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes `numen`

> [numen](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QiJhQqY)
>
> 1. m. Deidad dotada de un poder misterioso y fascinador.

La tercera acepción de "numen" es "musa", por cierto. Curiosamente las tres acepciones (incluida "musa") son nombres masculinos de acuerdo al DRAE.

Tienes también el mucho más rebuscado

> [estro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H05vNCx)
>
> 1. m. Inspiración ardiente del poeta o del artista.

Al contrario que "[vena](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bVcOttg)" o "[lira](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NPJpMwo%7CNPKEo9z)", que también pueden usarse para describir la inspiración artística o poética pero son nombres femeninos, `estro` y `numen` son masculinos.

Quizá podrías usar "numen" como alternativa masculina de "musa". Con "estro" me la juego a que no te entendería casi nadie.

Comment: Me ha encantado tu respuesta, Diego, nos has dejado a todos perplejos con tus descubrimientos, ¡cualquiera te la discute! :-D Recuérdame que te nomine a mejor respuesta de este trimestre.

Comment: Los que nos sabemos partes de "La venganza de don Mendo" conocemos perfectamente la palabra: ["Esas estrofas magnánimas son dignas del **estro** vuestro"](https://books.google.es/books?id=oo64cKrqwwkC&lpg=PA29&ots=hCUrVK8p8w&dq=esas%20estrofas%20magnanimas%20son%20dignas%20de%20estro%20vuestro&hl=es&pg=PA68#v=onepage&q&f=false).